# How to register an array of objects with v-model? Vue 2

Tags: vue.js

The first time that I dive into making this type of form with Vue, the issue is that I can't think of how to save the data inside the foreach that I generate with axios.

Where I would like to save the ID and the option selected with the input select as an object in order to make faster the match in the backend logic.

```
<template>
<div class="row" v-else>
    <div class=" col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" v-for="(project, index) in projects" :key="index">
        <fieldset class="border p-2 col-11">
            <legend class="w-auto col-12">Proyecto: {{project.name}}</legend>
            <b-form-group
                id="user_id"
                label="Reemplazante"
            >
                <b-form-select
                    v-model="formProject[index].us"
                    :options="project.users"
                    value-field="replacement_user_id"
                    text-field="replacement_user_name"
                    @change="addReemplacemet($event,project.id)"
                >
                    <template v-slot:first>
                        <b-form-select-option value="All">Seleccione</b-form-select-option>
                    </template>
                </b-form-select>
                <input type="hidden" name="project" v-model="formProject[index].proj">
            </b-form-group>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import skeleton from './skeleton/ProjectUserSkeleton.vue'

export default {
    name: 'ProjectsUser',
    components: { skeleton },
    props:{
        user: { type: String },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            user_id: null,
            showProject: false,
            projects: [],
            loadingProjects: true,
            formProject: [
                {
                    us: 'All',
                    proj: null
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    watch: {
        user: function() {
            this.viewProjects(this.user)
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async getProjects(salesman){
            this.loadingProjects = true
            await axios.get(route('users.getProjects'),{ 
                params: {
                    filter_user: salesman
                }
             })
                .then((res)=>{
                    this.projects = res.data.data

                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.loadingProjects = false
                    }, 800);
                })
        },
```

This is the form:

[image]

This is the message error:

[image]

Comment: The `formProject` data attribute only has 1 array value. If you want to use v-model then you will need make it a value of each `project`. eg. `project.us`

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, this looks like an issue with data. Your error suggests that you're trying to read an undefined variable.
It's often undesirable to use an index from iterating one array on another. In your Vue code, the index is `projects`, but you use it to access the variable `formProject`. This is usually undesirable because you can no longer expect that index to reference a defined variable (unless you're referencing the array you are currently iterating).
The easiest solution, for now, is to make sure the arrays are of the same length. Then utilizing v-if or other methods to not render the snippet if the variable is not defined.
A more complicated but better solution is restructuring your data such that `formProject` exists in `projects`